# row-major or column-major access of thread index in cuda?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, cuda

I'm confused whether an image is stored in row-major or column-major order in global memory of the device. 
I'am getting two different outputs of an image while accessing the image in both the orders.
When accessing in row-major order-

```
int x = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
int y = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;

int m = numCols * y + x;

if (x >= numCols || y >= numRows)
    return;

//marking column boundaries
if (x <= 2){                    
    d_Image[m].x = 255;
    d_Image[m].y = 0;
    d_Image[m].z = 0;
}
else if (x >= numCols-2){
    d_Image[m].x = 0;
    d_Image[m].y = 0;
    d_Image[m].z = 255;
}
else{
    d_Image[m].x = d_sample[m].x;
    d_Image[m].y = d_sample[m].y;
    d_Image[m].z = d_sample[m].z;
}
d_Image[m].w = d_sample[m].w;
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSTDP.jpg) using row-major
when accessing in column-major order-

```
int m = x * numRows + y;
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwELq.jpg) using col-major
**Dimensions-**

```
const dim3 blockSize(16,16);
const dim3 gridSize(numCols/16+1, numRows/16+1, 1);
blur << < gridSize, blockSize >> >(d_Image, d_sample, numRows, numCols);
```

I'm loading and saving the image using opencv.
In the first output red and blue dots are scattered all over the image. And in the second output(col-major) the boundary rows are marked while i'm trying to mark the columns. I'm too much confused.
**Edit**

```
void helper(uchar4* d_sample, uchar4* d_Image, size_t numRows, size_t numCols);

cv::Mat sample;
cv::Mat Image;

size_t numRows() { return sample.rows; }
size_t numCols() { return sample.cols; }

__global__ void blur(const uchar4 *d_sample, uchar4* d_Image, size_t numRows, size_t numCols){

  int x = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
  int y = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;

  int m = y*numCols + x;                    

  if (x >= numCols || y >= numRows)
        return;

  if (x <= 2){
      d_Image[m].x = 255;
      d_Image[m].y = 0;
      d_Image[m].z = 0;
  }
  else if (x >= (numCols-2)){
      d_Image[m].x = 0;
      d_Image[m].y = 0;
      d_Image[m].z = 255;
  }
  else{
      d_Image[m].x = d_sample[m].x;
      d_Image[m].y = d_sample[m].y;
      d_Image[m].z = d_sample[m].z;
  }
  d_Image[m].w = d_sample[m].w;
  }

int main(){

  uchar4  *h_sample, *d_sample, *d_Image, *h_Image;
  int filter[9];
  sample = cv::imread("sample.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  if (sample.empty()){
        std::cout << "error in loading image.";
        system("pause");
  }

  cv::cvtColor(sample,sample,CV_BGR2RGBA);
  Image.create(numRows(), numCols(), CV_8UC4);

  if (!sample.isContinuous() || !Image.isContinuous()) {
      std::cerr << "Images aren't continuous!! Exiting." << std::endl;
      system("pause");
      exit(1);
  }
  cv::cvtColor(Image,Image,CV_BGR2RGBA);

  h_sample = (uchar4*)sample.data;
  h_Image = (uchar4*)Image.data;

  size_t numPixels = numRows() * numCols();

    //allocate mmeory on device
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_sample, sizeof(uchar4) * numPixels));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Image, sizeof(uchar4) * numPixels));

  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(d_sample, 0, sizeof(uchar4) * numPixels));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(d_Image, 0, sizeof(uchar4) * numPixels));

//copy to device
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_sample, h_sample, sizeof(uchar4) * numPixels, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

  helper(d_sample, d_Image, numCols(), numRows());

//copy back to  host
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(h_Image, d_Image, sizeof(uchar4) * numPixels, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

  cv::cvtColor(Image,Image,CV_RGBA2BGR);

  cv::namedWindow("Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cv::imshow("Image", Image);
  cv::waitKey(0);
  cv::imwrite("sample.jpg", Image);

  return 0;
}

void helper(uchar4* d_sample, uchar4* d_Image, size_t numRows, size_t numCols){

  const dim3 blockSize(16,16);
  const dim3 gridSize(numCols/16+1, numRows/16+1, 1);
  blur << < gridSize, blockSize >> >(d_sample, d_Image, numRows, numCols);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are viewing your resultant memory/image correctly?  Are you perhaps saving/displaying the image using column major while everything else is row major for example?

Comment: opencv stores mat/image data in row-major, if that helps...

Comment: AFAIK  the device allocation underlying a `cv::cuda::GpuMat` is a pitched allocation.  I don't know if that is what you are using or not since you haven't shown a complete code (questions asking  "why isn't this code working?" are expected to include a [mcve]).  But your posted code doesn't appear to be accounting for a pitched allocation.  Refer to slide 15 [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/webinar/gtc-express-itseez-opencv-webinar.pdf)

Comment: @RobertCrovella please correct me. I've uploaded the full code.

Comment: @Dharmendar: what "full code" would that be?

Comment: @talonmies i"m bad in english. I was referring to the methods used in loading and saving the image. And i"m still confused.

Comment: could your post your code **with** the function signature, as we need to see the types so we can tell if the stride is correct, of if input parameters are switched...

Answer (score 1):

```
void helper(uchar4* d_sample, uchar4* d_Image, size_t numRows, size_t numCols){
```

and you call

```
helper(d_sample, d_Image, numCols(), numRows());
```

I think you may have switched cols and rows when you call helper...